# Font Descriptors and Symbolic Traits

Tags: objective-c, uikit, nsdictionary, textkit

```
UIFontDescriptor *bodyFontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
UIFontDescriptor *italicBoldDescriptor = [bodyFontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute : @{ UIFontSymbolicTrait: @(UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic | UIFontDescriptorTraitBold)}}];
UIFont *comboFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:italicBoldDescriptor size:0.0];
[self.body.textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:comboFont range:self.body.selectedRange];
```

My goal was to bold/italic selected text in a text view. After doing a bit of research, this is what I have and it works! However, I really do not understand the code, especially the second line. If someone could explain exactly what this code is doing I would greatly appreciate it. Also I do not understand the dictionary syntax that is happening in the second line. What is the syntax with the '|' character? I have never seen that before. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute`, An NSDictionary instance instance fully describing font traits. The default value is supplied by the font.

`UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits` symbolically describes stylistic aspects of a font.

You can check [iOS Developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits)

Answer (score 1):

The "|" operator is the C bit-OR which is combining two flag values into a single number.

Apple's doc for [bold](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptorsymbolictraits/uifontdescriptortraitbold?language=objc) shows it as `UIFontDescriptorTraitBold = 1u << 1`
and for [italic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptorsymbolictraits/uifontdescriptortraititalic?language=objc) as `UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic = 1u << 0`.

So that OR clause is combining the binary values 0b00000010 and 0b00000001 to make a single flag 0b00000011.